# How to compare a variable with local storage in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Below is the code I use in Chrome extension which gets a url from local storage and compares it with current url of the webpage..

The problem is javascript is not showing them as equal even though they are one and the same..(Below a=http://www.google.com and b=http://www.google.com)

```
var a="";
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "url"}, function(response) {
a=response.data;
});
var b = document.location;

//I am trying to compare a and b but I always get they are equal even though they are one and the same

 if (a==b)
 {
   alert("Equal");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait the response callback function. Change you code to:

```
var a="";
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "url"}, function(response) {
  a=response.data;
  var b = document.location;
   if (a==b)
   {
     alert("Equal");
   }
});
```

Comment: I will try it out but even with my code it's displaying correct only..When I use a separate alert box to display a,it's displaying correctly whereas it's not comparing correctly..

Comment: Try to use `console.log()` in place of `alert()`. You can add `console.log()` after every line in your code and look at the real code workflow. Or use script debuger step by step.

Answer (score 0):

what is the datatype of variable 'a'
how about this way of

```
function (response) {
    a += response.data;
}
```